# I can connect to a USB device from a C# Console App but not from a WinForms App

Tags: c#, .net, usb, .net-4.7.2

I have a C# class library that manages communication to a custom USB Device.
This is a proprietary application so I can't directly share the code but I can share information about how the build is configured and share appropriate code snippets.

- My target system is Windows 10 .NET Framework 4.7.2
- My Development Platform is Visual Studio 2019
- All the projects are C# .NET Framework 4.7.2
- There is a WinForms App and a Console App - both use the same library classes
- Everything is in a single solution

When I run the Console Application the USB device connects and communicates fine but when I run the WinForms Application the connection request times out - DeviceAccessInformation returns "DeniedBySystem".

The library connects to the USB Device using Windows.Devices.Usb.UsbDevice

The connection request is done via:

```
Task<UsbDevice> openAsyncTask = UsbDevice.FromIdAsync(connectionId).AsTask(cancellationToken);
UsbDevice usbDevice = await openAsyncTask;
```

I check the DeviceAccessInformation using:

```
var deviceAccessStatus = DeviceAccessInformation.CreateFromId(connectionId).CurrentStatus;
```

- Why the difference between the Console App and the WinForms App?
- What do I need to do to get the WinForms App to work (connect to the USB device)?

Comment: Are they running as the same user account?  Both equally elevated (or non-elevated)?  Both Full Trust vs Partial Trust?

Comment: Yes, I run both applications identically - both directly and from the debugger (by changing the Startup Project).  I also tried "Run as Administrator" on the WinForms App and it did the same thing.  I also increased the timeout to 20s and that didn't work either.  The thread blocks seemingly forever at the await.

Comment: "From the debugger" may be part of the problem.  Check the setting for "Visual Studio hosting process" in each project's Debug launch properties.

Comment: It still fails the same way if I right-click on the .exe and select "Run as Administrator".

Comment: If you use `EDITBIN` to change the /subsystem of the application built as WinForms to Console, does the resulting .exe act like the directly-compiled WinForms app or like the console app?